# MS-Access: Assign records to 4 persons, with each has the same number of records

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access-2007, grouping, partition

The task was say I have 4000 (Or n) Customer IDs in cutomer table, and I need to assign them to 4 persons to have each of them taking care of 1000 (or N/4) customer IDs, 
I tried partition, but it gives me the result so wrong with 5: in each record.

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_ID, Partition (CUSTOMER_ID, 1, 4, (SELECT ROUND(Sum(B.C)/4,0) AS   
Employee_ID FROM (SELECT CUSTOMER_ID, Count(CUSTOMER_ID) AS C FROM CUSTOMER GROUP BY 
CUSTOMER_NAME) AS B)/4)
FROM CUSTOMER
GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ID;
```

Comment: partition on row number instead.

Comment: @MarcB I tried but this time it just show "You tried to excute a query that does not included the specified expression 'Partition(ID,1,4,5000)' AS PART OF AN AGGREATE FUNCTION" 'SELECT CUSTOMER_ID, Partition([ROWID],1,4,5000) AS Employee_ID FROM CUSTOMER GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ID;'

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it. For test data

```
CUSTOMER_ID
-----------
          1
          2
          4
          7
          8
         11
         13
         14
         15
...
```

the query

```sql
SELECT c1.CUSTOMER_ID, COUNT(*) AS RankIndex
FROM CUSTOMER c1 INNER JOIN CUSTOMER c2 ON c1.CUSTOMER_ID >= c2.CUSTOMER_ID
GROUP BY c1.CUSTOMER_ID
```

will produce

```
CUSTOMER_ID  RankIndex
-----------  ---------
          1          1  
          2          2
          4          3
          7          4
          8          5
         11          6
         13          7
         14          8
         15          9
...
```

so if we do some Modulo 4 arithmetic on the `COUNT(*)` and name it [Employee_ID], like so

```sql
SELECT c1.CUSTOMER_ID, ((COUNT(*) - 1) Mod 4) AS Employee_ID
FROM CUSTOMER c1 INNER JOIN CUSTOMER c2 ON c1.CUSTOMER_ID >= c2.CUSTOMER_ID
GROUP BY c1.CUSTOMER_ID
```

we get

```
CUSTOMER_ID  Employee_ID
-----------  -----------
          1            0  
          2            1
          4            2
          7            3
          8            0
         11            1
         13            2
         14            3
         15            0
...
```

Comment: Hi Gord, I tried this query, but the access kept running it for the last one hour haven't finish yet by now